# remove chart controls dynamically

Tags: c#

I have created a chart dynamically, is there a way to remove it?
I want to create a `button_click` to remove the chart. Any advise? Especially this is created locally.

```
private void createchart()
{ 
    var chartA = new Chart();
    chartA.Size = new Size(50,50);
    chartA.Left = coord_X2;
    chartA.Top = coord_Y2;

    var chartArea = new ChartArea();

    chartA.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

    var series = new Series();
    series.Name = "TT";
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
    series.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    chartA.Series.Add(series);

    chartA.Series["TT"].Points.AddXY("score", dr["Score"]);

    this.Controls.Add(chartA);
}
```

thanks a mil
Jeff

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: `this.Controls.Remove(chartA);`?

Comment: can't cause private void btn_clear_Click() cannot identify "chartA" and the chart is created within a private void createchart()

Answer (score 0):

If you give it a `Name` like this:

```
chartA.Name = "myUniqueChartName";
```

you can remove it by that `Name`:

```
this.Controls.Remove(this.Controls["myUniqueChartName"]);
```

If the `Name` is not unique the `Remove` statement will first remove the first control of that name added and on each further call remove the next one added..